# Ubuntu automatically reset my screen brightness after screen lock

Tags: 16.04, brightness, amd-graphics

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. My laptop model is Toshiba Satellite L600 and therefore the graphic card is ATI Mobility Radeon HD5145. I find that each time I wake my screen from a lock by inactivating for 5 mins, the brightness is reset to a default value, resulting repeated brightness adjusting actions. May I know why Ubuntu 16.04 is so and how to avoid such brightness resetting?

Comment: Probably has no solution and not really a problem, honestly.

Comment: It is really a problem, honestly